# How to show the congruence involving the divisor function

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Prove that if $n \in \mathbb{N}$;  $n \equiv -1$   $(mod 24)$ $\Longrightarrow $$ \sigma(n) \equiv 0$  $ (mod 24)  $

where $\sigma $ is the divisor function.

my try:

if $n \equiv -1$   $(mod 24)$ then  $24|n+1$  which means that

$ \exists k, k \in \mathbb{Z}$ such as   $n+1 =  24 k$

but from here i can not link the result with $\sigma(n)$

Answer (score 1):

By chinese remainder theorem we can say
$$
n \equiv -1 (mod 24) \Leftrightarrow n \equiv -1 (mod3) \wedge   n \equiv -1 (mod8).
$$
So n can not be a square because $n\equiv -1 (mod 8).$

Now
$$
\alpha | n \Rightarrow  \alpha \neq \frac{n}{\alpha} 
$$$$
2\sigma(n)=\sum_{\alpha|n}( \alpha + \frac{n}{\alpha}) 
$$$$
\alpha + \frac{n}{\alpha} = \alpha + \frac{24k - 1}{\alpha} \equiv \alpha - \frac{1}{\alpha} (mod24)
$$ Now
$$
  \alpha - \frac{1}{\alpha} \equiv \alpha^2 -1 \equiv 0 (mod 24) \forall \alpha \in \mathbb{Z}_{24}^*
$$

Comment: On a different matter, I think you might be interested in this. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958206/describe-the-automorphisms-of-this-mathbfz-module

Answer (score 1):

As $n\equiv-1\pmod{24}\iff24|(n+1); (n,24)=1\implies $ any divisor of $n$ is co-prime with $24$

So, all the divisors$(d)$ of $n$ must be $\equiv1,5,7,11,13,17,19,23\pmod{24}$

If $d\equiv1\pmod{24},\dfrac nd\equiv-1\equiv23\pmod{24}$

So, $d+\dfrac nd\equiv0\pmod{24}$

Similarly for other $d\equiv5,7,11,13,17,19,23\pmod{24}$