# Describe the automorphisms of this $\mathbf{Z}$-module

Tags: modules, abstract-algebra

This follows up on what I thought was a good question which has now been deleted, asking about the automorphisms of the multiplicative group $\mathbf{Q}^{*}$.

Is there a relatively simple description, in group-theoretic terms, of the group of automorphisms of the $\mathbf{Z}$-module $\bigoplus_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mathbf{Z}$?

And can such a description be given if instead we have $(\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}) \oplus \bigoplus_{n \in \mathbf{N}} \mathbf{Z}$?

I see that the factor $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ would need to be preserved under any automorphism, since it is the torsion submodule.

Comment: The link seems to have been deleted.

Comment: @user180040 Pardon, I read that as a general direct sum, I see now that it's very specific.

Comment: It's probably still important to point out that this group, whatever it is, contains lots of copies of the group of invertible linear matrices.  It's something like an infinite matrix group, but my intuition for such things is quite limited.

Comment: In particular, you can pick any basis and any permutation of that basis.  So this is a really gigantic group, and I have a feeling that there are some foundational (i.e. logic/set theory) considerations at play here.

Comment: I understand that it must contain many subgroups isomorphic to $\operatorname{Gl}_n(\mathbf{Z})$. But it occasionally happens that something contains lots of complicated subgroups and is still simple, or at least has a name. Also, I would like to know if the group of automorphisms of the second module can be described in a simple way that relates it to the first, even if that group is complicated. I see that the first group would be a quotient of the second, since the first module is the quotient of the second by $\mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$, and that summand is preserved under any automorphism.